# JavaScript: document.write() not working in Mac Terminal

Tags: javascript, parsing, serverside-javascript

I'm trying to include some libraries in from some server scripts that I'm running from the Mac Terminal (command line).  This will not be run in a browser - I'm using Parse Cloud Code for my iOS app's backend.  Any ideas why the following code would not work, whereas it does work in Google Chrome?

```
document.write('<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
document.write('<script src="https://raw.github.com/carlo/jquery-base64/master/ jquery.base64.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
document.write('<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.0.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```

Running this from the terminal gives the error: {"code":141,"error":"Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined"}.

Comment: Thumb rule for checking if javascript works somewhere: do an `alert(1);`

Comment: `Parse Cloud Code` is running node.js or some other server side JS (like rhino)?

Comment: @nickd717 Make sure to edit your question to accurately reflect the error.

Comment: @SimonBoudrias - Not sure. Here is the documentation, but I've found it tough to figure out exactly how it works on a basic level: https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started.

Answer (score 0):

there's usually no `document` in server side Javascript. This is because there's no DOM being created, and that's why you get that error (`Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined`).

Also, usually, `script` tags won't be use to load in javascript file (there's no DOM).

Node.js use a module interface using `require` to request modules (this also mean module won't be used in the global space; e.g. `window` in the browser, `process` in Node.js). And unfortunately, a lot of client side javascript library won't work on the server side (that's the case of jQuery because it is used to manipulate DOM which is not present server side).

In node however, there's [`cheerio`](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) who basically implement jQuery syntax on the server to generate DOM string. But in your case, I'd rather looks for specific library working on your environnement.

**Enaway**, after you clarified your question a little bit. I think you have an answer to why you get the `document not defined` error (you're not working in a browser, and as so you have no DOM). From there, you'll really need to read `Cloud Code Guide` documentation and see how their environment is working; but definitly, it's not because it says it uses javascript that you can transpose how you work on the browser to the server.

I wish you good luck.